# What is the opposite of Textbox.text = ""

Tags: string, vb.net, textbox, is-empty

Do you know the opposite of Textbox1.text = "" ?
Or how to do this Textbox1.text = not empty ?
Because I want the user to enter characters on the textbox.

Example:
If the user checked this radiobutton(Yes/No), the textbox beside it must be filled.
Just like the question: Are you confident? If yes, Why?

Comment: All depends on what is considered 'empty' with regards to whitespace (spaces, tabs, ...)
Use String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text)

Comment: E.g., `If not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text.Trim())` -- Note that Empty and Null are two different things

Comment: Is this correct?

`If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            MsgBox("Complete")
        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox10.Text.Trim()) Then
                MsgBox("Complete")
            Else
                MsgBox("Empty textbox")

            End If
        End If`

Comment: Or this?

Or

`If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
            MsgBox("Complete")
        ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox11.Text) Then
                MsgBox("Empty textbox")
            Else
                MsgBox("Complete")
            End If
        End If`

Comment: Is there a way to use that code without using IF?

Example: 
`If RadioButton1.Checked = True Or RadioButton2.Checked = True  Then
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)`

Comment: Either the user types into the TextBox or the program sets it: `Textbox1.text = "Your text goes here"`.

Answer (score 0):

Got some answers from Jimi and Emond. They helped me with this codes.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        MsgBox("Complete")
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox10.Text.Trim()) Then
            MsgBox("Complete")
        Else
            MsgBox("Empty textbox")

        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        MsgBox("Complete")
    ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox11.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Empty textbox")
        Else
            MsgBox("Complete")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Except don't use `MsgBox()` in WinForms. Use `MessageBox.Show()` instead. I've seen cases where the deprecated MsgBox somehow shows its dialog behind the active Form instead of in front of it.

Comment: oHHH... I thought Msgbox() and MessageBox.Show() are the same.

Comment: `MsgBox()` was put in for backwards compatibility when they first switched over from old-school VB6 to VisualBasic.Net (way back in 2002!), so that old programs could be converted with fewer visual code changes. Technically speaking, `MsgBox()` is a Function, while `MessageBox` is a Class that has a method called `Show()`. When you use `MsgBox()`, it actually calls `MessageBox.Show()` for you. There are obviously other differences in the way they are called and used. `MessageBox.Show()` is more strict in its usage and return types.

Comment: Thank you. I will add that to my learning list.